# Display woocommerce product variations as single products on shop page and ajax load more

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have displayed wc product's variations as a single product.

Here is link: https://hueslabsstage.wpengine.com/store/
also, you need credentials:
login: hueslabsstage
password: 11test11

I have an issue with ajax load more function. I am using WooCommerce Load More Products by BeRocket. For example, when I choose 2 products to show on load more it really shows 2 products, but with all variations. For example, I have 4 products, the first one and the second one with 2 variations, so the plugin shows me 4 items on the shop page(2 products with 2 variations).
So, I need to display each variation as a single product in the way the plugin sees products. In order to when I choose 2 products to show, the plugin should display 2 variations of the product, instead of 2 products with them all variations.
Hope I explained my issue correctly.
My content-product.php:

```
<?php 
    if ($product->is_type('variable')): ?>
        <?php
        $unique_variations = [];

        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $key => $item) {
            if (!variation_exists($item['attributes']['attribute_pa_color'], 'attribute_pa_color', $unique_variations)) {
                $unique_variations[] = $item;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <?php foreach($unique_variations as $variation): 
            $itemVariation = $variation['variation_id'];
            ?>
            <?php
                $meta = get_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_color', true);
                if (empty($meta)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, 'pa_color');
                $color = get_field('product_color', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
                $gallery = get_field('gallery', $variation['variation_id']);
                $front_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($variation['image_id'], 'product-thumbnail')[0];
                $back_image = null;

                if (!empty($gallery)) {
                    $back_image = $gallery[0]['sizes']['product-thumbnail'];
                }
            ?>
                <article class="<?php echo $outOfStock; ?>">
                    <?php if ($product_status_badge): ?>
                        <div class="product_badge">
                            <img src="<?php echo $product_status_badge; ?>" alt="Product status">
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="product_images">
                        <?php 
                            if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() ){
                                ?>
                                    <div class="out_of_stock_overlay">Sold Out</div>
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="product_image_items">
                            <figure>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() ?>?attribute_pa_color=<?php echo $meta ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $item['image']['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" class="front_img">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $back_image;?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" data-test="<?php echo $back_image;?>" class="back_img">
                                </a>
                                <div class="product_arrows">
                                    <div class="arrow_left">
                                        <em class="fal fa-chevron-left"></em>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="arrow_right">
                                        <em class="fal fa-chevron-right"></em>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_top">
                        <div class="product_left">
                            <h3 class="product_title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>

                            <div class="price">
                                <?php if ($product->is_type('variable')): ?>
                                    <?php echo $product->get_variation_price() . " " . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if ($product->is_type('variable')): ?>
                            <?php
                            $unique_variations = [];

                            foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $key => $item) {
                                if (!variation_exists($item['attributes']['attribute_pa_color'], 'attribute_pa_color', $unique_variations)) {
                                    $unique_variations[] = $item;
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="product_right">
                                <ul class="product_variations_list">
                                    <?php foreach($unique_variations as $variation): ?>
                                        <?php
                                            $meta = get_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_color', true);
                                            if (empty($meta)) {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                            $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, 'pa_color');
                                            $color = get_field('product_color', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
                                            $gallery = get_field('gallery', $variation['variation_id']);
                                            $front_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($variation['image_id'], 'product-thumbnail')[0];
                                            $back_image = null;

                                            if (!empty($gallery)) {
                                                $back_image = $gallery[0]['sizes']['product-thumbnail'];
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="<?php echo $variation['variation_id'] == $itemVariation ? 'active' : ''; ?>" data-variation-id="<?php echo $variation['variation_id']; ?>" data-variation-image="<?php echo $front_image; ?>" data-variation-back-image="<?php echo $back_image; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>?attribute_pa_color=<?php echo $term->slug;?>" title="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                                                <em class="fas fa-certificate primary" style="color: <?php echo $color ;?>;"></em>
                                                <em class="fas fa-certificate secondary"></em>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_bottom">
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
                                <?php $image = get_field('image', 'pa_specifications_' . $attribute->term_id); ?>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $attribute->name; ?>">
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </article>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif;

?>
```

archive-product.php is not changed :

```
if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
}
```

Comment: it's showing 2 products with them all variations instead of 2 variations of the product because as per ajax load more function it's fetching the 2nd-page products. so I think you need to do custom code or customize ajax to load more function.